# Zookeeper Newbie - Which nodes do I read and write?  Should I load balance?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am a zookeeper newbie.  I have three nodes in three separate data centers.  I will need to read and write data from the python pykeeper API? So...

1) which node to I read and write from?  Does it matter?  Round robin?  Write to master, read from slaves?

2) How do I know wich server was elected as master? Do I care? That I have yet to figure out.

3) For now I am using the following to connect to zookeeper.

```
import zc.zk
from random import choice
zk_servers = ['111.111.111.111:2181','111.111.111.222:2181','111.111.111.333:2181']
zk = zc.zk.ZooKeeper(choice(zk_servers))
```

This begs the question, what if a zk node fails?  Should I place nodes behind HA proxy to load-balance the requests?

Any advice for using best practice for reading and writing to zk nodes is mush appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you should probably start by reading the docs, http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.3/zookeeperOver.html

Answer (score 0):

The general model is that you supply your clients with the list of server nodes and then connect to the cluster as a whole.  ZooKeeper shuffles the list of server addresses and then connects to one.  You don't pick various servers to do individual tasks...part of the point of zookeeper is that it scales horizontally by adding more nodes...each of which responds to reads and to writes based on what data is being requested and where the cluster has put it.

Comment: This comment isn't true. The same data resides on all nodes. It doesn't matter which data you request. As such, Zookeeper does _not_ scale horizontally with respect to data. It _does_, however, scale horizontally in terms of reads.